# Is using a hash a suitable way to hide information I need verified by a user?

Tags: cryptography

I have two applications, one with a list of users and their emails (App A), and one which has neither (App B).

I need to send a link from A to some of the users with a link to B, and when they get to B, I want to be able to ask them what their username is within B, and confirm that it is the person who I sent the email to from A.

My thought is that I can send an email with a link http://AppB/something?code={code}, with {code} being a hash of (the username concatenated with some pre-shared secret between A and B).

Functionally, this would work. But is it secure? In other words, as a malicious user, I can't guess the hash which would come from another username, nor can I derive the secret.

For the sake of argument about the goal, assume that I can't use a symmetric encryption algorithm, which would presumably be able to accomplish a similar goal.

My impression is that, yes, this would be secure - it's effectively the same as saying, if I know the first x characters of the input to some hash, can I know the rest? Presumably it would be easier, but depending on the length of the shared secret would take a lot of guessing. I would also need to be aware that this was the method being used, the hashing algorithm, and so on.